# TLS Support in .Net SslStream

Tags: .net, network-programming, tcpclient, starttls

I am a beginner in networking with VB2010 and .Net4. To get things working, I am trying to write my own TCP Client, inherited from the one given by the .Net BCL, and extending it with some routines for sending and receiving and eventually some events.

I want to use the STARTTLS command, which is useful for Mail Servers. I searched and know that other protocols support this command like FTP and NNTP. Can this command be used for all servers, or just some of them?

Answer (score 0):

Each protocol that supports TLS will have a method of handing control over to TLS and handing it back. Some take the simple approach of listening on a different port and negotiating TLS immediately on connection. Others will have a brief exchange in unsecured mode before both sides hand over to TLS. Search for the document (RFC) that describes the protocol you'd like to implement to see how it does it.